# For loop generated multithreads can't use synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading

I use "for" loop to generate 100 threads that print out data 0~4.

```
public class ThreadTest implements Runnable {
    static volatile int threadNum = 100;
    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " synchronized loop " + i);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < threadNum; i++) {
            ThreadTest t = new ThreadTest();
            Thread t1 = new Thread(t);
            t1.start();
        }
    }
}
```

I once hope to get the data 0~4 in order for each thread because the "synchronized" only allow one thread to operate the "for" loop. However, the printed result is not as I expected.

[image]

Can anyone help me to point our what my problem is? Thank you~

Comment: Hint: avoid posting screen shots. Your output is "pure text"; so it would be much easier for you to simply do copy/paste of that text.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you `synchronize` the access on the current `ThreadTest` instance (using `synchronized (this)`) and you have one such instance per thread so it is useless, you should instead synchronize on a common mutex like the class for example as we have only one instance of class as next:

```
synchronized (ThreadTest.class) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " synchronized loop " + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is solved after I modified my code as you suggested. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Everything as to be expected here.

Thing is: each of your ThreadTest object is synchronizing on its **this** pointer.

What do you expect to happen when you give 100 people 100 spoons and 100 bowls and tell them to start eating? Maybe, if you would have only 1 spoon in total for the 100 people, would that change something?

Long story short: you have to sync on **one** object, not on 100 different ones.